# Angular JS 1.3+ One time binding for ng-bind with a ternary condition

Tags: angularjs, binding

Would this be correct if I need to use one time binding for a ternary condition inside data-ng-bind directive?

```
<span data-ng-bind="::model.boolean ? 'json.item.value1' : 'json.item.value2'"></span>
```

or

```
<span data-ng-bind="::(model.boolean ? 'json.item.value1' : 'json.item.value2')"></span>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. The whole expression, whatever it is, will be parsed and read once.

What will happen internally would be equivalent to:

```
// If not bound
value = $parse("model.boolean ? 'json.item.value1' : 'json.item.value2'")(scope)
```

**Note**: If `model.boolean` is true, you will actually see the string `"json.item.value1"` and not the real value it contains. If you want to evaluate that, you need to remove the single quotes `'` so it becomes:

```
<span data-ng-bind="::model.boolean ? json.item.value1 : json.item.value2"></span>
```

Comment: So Assuming `model.boolean === true` **can we still one time bind**?

Comment: If the boolean is true, your binding will become `'json.item.value1'` and never change again. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Oh I understand the question better with your edit. The parenthesis won't change anything: the one time binding applies to the whole expression, just because it starts with `::` is enought. Also I have added a note to my answer as you may not get what you expect

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to accept the answer if that's it so it can help the community, thanks :)

Comment: Although I believe one-time-binding will not work In a ternary condition because that makes it two way data-binding.
If the statement changes(**model.boolean === false** ) then one-time-binding will remain the same.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean :/ There is no two-way binding involved here, it is text-binding with interpolation, and this will happen only once, nothing will happen when model.boolean changes again. If that is not what you want you should remove `::`